# What phrase can I use to tell about my schooling and college?

Tags: grammaire

is this correct?
J'ai fait ma scolarité de Mount Carmel école

Answer (score 3):

You could say things like :

> J'ai fait ma scolarité à l'école de Mont-Carmel (if you want to translate even the school's name)

Or

> J'ai fait ma scolarité à l'école "Mount Carmel" (which would be the best choice in my opinion)

In both sentences, *ma scolarité* can be replaced by *mes études*.

*École* can be replaced by *université* or *faculté*. *École* is said when you are in something like an engineering/business school, while the other ones would be more adapted for actual colleges.

Comment: and how about word "graduation"? it equivalent word in french?

Comment: If you wish to say "I graduated from" etc., one way to say it is "Je suis diplômé de (l'école)", or "j'ai eu mon diplôme à (l'école)".